# Computing the surface integral of $\ G(x,y,z) = xyz $ over the triangular surface with vertices $(1,0,0),\,(0,2,0)$ and $(0,1,1)$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

I was attempting to compute the surface integral of $\ G(x,y,z) = \ xyz $ over the triangular surface with vertices at $\ (1,0,0)$, $\ (0,2,0)$ and $\ (0,1,1)$.

[image]

Clearly, the first step is to parametrize the region. I thought of two approaches :

The first approach was choosing $\ x$ and $\ y $ as my parameters and rewriting $\ z $ as a function of $\ x$ and $\ y$, then projecting the above triangular surface onto the $\ xy $ plane to find the upper and lower bounds of the required surface integral.

The surface is given by the equation:

$$\ 2x + y + z = 2 $$

Then, we can use the formula:

$$ \ dS = \sqrt(1+f_x^2+f_y^2) \cdot dx dy $$

Since the normal vector of our projection is along the positive z direction.

So, I expressed $\ z$ in terms of $\ x$ and $\ y$, substituted $\ z(x,y) $ into G and obtained the double integral in terms of $\ x$ and $\ y$.

But I am having some trouble identifying the bounds of the double integral. It is obvious that 0 <= $\ x $ <= 1, but what should be the bounds for y?

I tried sketching the shadow of the triangular region on the $\ xy $ plane by moving the point $\ (0,1,1)$ to $\ (0,1,0)$ and computing the bounds for $\ y $ for a given $\ x$.

Doing that, I got $\ (1-x) <= y <= (2-2x) $ but I am unable to obtain the correct answer via this method.

So then, I thought of another method. I thought of doing the same thing with the $\ x-z $ plane instead of the $\ xy $ plane. The triangular surface remains the same and the integrand also remains the same if we simply swap out $\ y$ with $\ z$.

But I am also confused about the bounds in this case. If I project the point $\ (0,1,1)$ onto $\ (0,0,1)$ and the point $\ (0,2,0)$ to $\ (0,0,0)$, I get the bounds of z as $\ 0$ <= $\ z$ <= $\ (1-x) $. I am yet again getting an incorrect answer with this.

It is possible that the source I am checking for answers is incorrect itself. The answers I am obtaining via both methods is $\frac{\sqrt6}{30}$, while the answer given is $\frac{\sqrt6}{15}$.

Can someone please clarify the appropriate procedure to find the correct bounds in this question, and the correct answer if possible?

Comment: Projection on the $xy$-plane is certainly simplest. So what is the projection of the surface $S$ onto the $xy$-plane? Two of the points are clear. The projection of $(0,1,1)$ is the point $(0,1,0)$, as you said, so the projection of $S$ will have boundary the line segment from $(1,0)$ to $(0,1)$, the line segment from $(0,1)$ to $(0,2)$, and the line segment from $(0,2)$ to $(1,0)$. So this gives $\int_0^1\int_{1-x}^{2(1-x)}\dots dy\,dx$. You had this correct in your analysis. At this juncture, it's impossible to tell what you did wrong (if anything).

Comment: Your bounds are pretty easy. $z \geq 0, x \geq 0$ and $y \geq z$. Plus being on the triangle plane you identified, ofc...

Comment: @Surge Huh? Explain what you're talking about.

Comment: @TedShifrin It's just tedious, no? His triangle is the plane of the triangle with the bounds given by the planes determined by $z = 0$, $x  = 0$ and $y = z$.

Comment: I would project on the $yz$ plane myself. Then you're integrating on the triangle $\{(0,0,0), (0,1,1),(0,2,0)\}$.

Comment: Yes, in point of fact, the projection on the $xy$-plane is "least simple," but it's still straightforward. Something else is going wrong with the OP's solution. I suspect there may also be a wrong answer at the back of the book.

Comment: @Surge If you're projecting on the y-z plane, the bounds would be of the form 0 <= z <= 1, z <= y <= 2-z.

Comment: @TedShifrin That's what I am also thinking, since I computed the integral via all three methods, examined for all calculation errors via WolframAlpha and still got the same result.

Comment: Unless you miscomputed the "fudge factor," which I doubt, stop worrying about it. :)

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Project the triangle on the $y-z$ plane. Then the surface over which we're integrating is $\{(0,0,0),(0,1,1),(0,2,0)\}$, or in the $y-z$ plane, the triangle is $\{(0,0),(1,1),(2,0)\}$. Let's denote it with $D$.
We have $x = (2 - y - z)/2$. If the surface is given by $(f(y,z),y,z)$,
$$
dS = \sqrt{1 + f_y^2 + f_z^2}dydz = \sqrt{1 + 1/4 + 1/4}dydz = \frac{\sqrt{6}}{2}dydz. 
$$
So the integral is
$$
\int_D yz\frac{2 - y - z}{2} \frac{\sqrt{6}}{2}dydz = \frac{\sqrt{6}}{2} \left( \int_0^1dy\left(\int_0^y yz\frac{2-y-z}{2}dz\right) + \int_1^2dy\left(\int_0^{2-y}yz\frac{2-y-z}{2}dz\right) \right)
$$
$$
= \frac{\sqrt{6}}{2}\int_0^1\left(\frac{y^3}{2} - \frac{y^4}{4} - \frac{y^4}{6}\right)dy + \frac{\sqrt{6}}{2}\int_1^2\left(
- \frac{y \left(2 - y\right)^{3}}{6} + \left(2 - y\right)^{2} \left(- \frac{y^{2}}{4} + \frac{y}{2}\right)\right)dy
$$
$$
= \frac{\sqrt{6}}{48} + \frac{\sqrt{6}}{80} = \frac{\sqrt{6}}{30}.
$$
I used `Sympy` so hopefully I did not mess the details up.

Comment: I think you missed the sqrt(6) factor, since dS is not directly equal to dydz.

Comment: Ahh! Good point... I'll fix it now.